# How to get verified status of Facebook user in Facebook sdk v3.12

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk

I am trying to access the verified status of the logged in user.Below is the code which is have tried so faar.I am getting verified value as null when i login using this code.Is there any other permission which i need to add in order to access verified status?
Any help will be greatfull.

**Login**

```
FBLoginView *loginView =[[FBLoginView alloc] initWithReadPermissions:@[@"basic_info", @"email", @"user_birthday",@"user_location"]];
    loginView.delegate=self;
    [self.view addSubview:loginView];
```

**Login delgate method**

```
- (void)loginViewFetchedUserInfo:(FBLoginView *)loginView
                            user:(id<FBGraphUser>)user {
NSLog(@"userInfo %@",[user objectForKey:@"verified"]);
}
```

Comment: what do you get when you log the whole of the user object? I've had a look at the Facebook code on github and the controller is supposed to do a "request for me" so it should contain the verified key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it.It was the "user_status" permission which i had to add in order to get the verified status.

```
FBLoginView *loginView =[[FBLoginView alloc] initWithReadPermissions:@[@"basic_info", @"email", @"user_birthday",@"user_location",@"user_status"]];
```